# Rubyでnewを使わずにインスタンス化できるクラスの作り方

Tags: ruby

ActiveRecordみたいな`Post.all`のように`new`を使わずに使えるクラスってどうやって作るのでしょうか。

例えば`Person`というクラスに対して何らかの定義をすることで、

```
Person('yoshida').age
```

とできるような使い方を考えています。

また、これの名前みたいなのはあるのでしょうか。インスタンスレスクラス的な。

Comment: コメント内で言及されていたコード例を追加しました。ActiveRecordへの言及が不要になっているかもしれませんので、お手数ですが、必要に応じて[edit]をおねがいします。

Answer (score 5):

インスタンスメソッドではなくクラスメソッドを作ります。

```
class Post
  def self.all
    [1,2,3]
  end
end

p Post.all
```

Comment: `Post('arg').all`としたいときはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。`self.initialize(arg)`ではないですよね・・・

Comment: ruby だと Post(x) は main モジュール内の Post という関数を呼び出すという意味になります。ですので上記のコードでは実現出来ません。

Comment: ちなみに `Post.all("arg")` ではないですか？でしたら `def self.all(*args)` とすれば可変個引数が受け取れます。

Comment: たとえば`Post(id).name`というようなものを作りたいのですが、何か良いアイデアはないでしょうか・・・

Comment: `Post.find(id).name` と書かない理由はなんでしょうか？

Comment: すみません`Activerecord`を例に出したのがまずかったですよね。`Person('yoshida').age`という感じで`yoshida`というオブジェクトが直接作れればと考えたのですが。

Comment: `yoshida というオブジェクト` とは、https://gist.github.com/mattn/394d1f7a76bff875d3d7 こういう意味でしょうか？それとも https://gist.github.com/mattn/394d1f7a76bff875d3d7/e12846d5be645da1fd73356ffd9301c110158e92 という意味でしょうか？

Comment: 後者です!挙動としてもこれが理想です。これを`Class`の内で行いたいと考えていました。

Answer (score 2):

`Post['ruby'].name`のような書き方であれば、Rubyで実現できます。
しかしながら、`Post.find('ruby').name`のようなメソッドチェインを用いるクラス設計の方がRubyらしい書き方だと考えています。

```
class Post
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def self.[](name)
    new(name)
  end
end

puts Post["ruby"].name #=> ruby
```

Answer (score 2):

「クラスに対して何らかの定義」ではありませんが、クラスとは別に、同じ名前のメソッドを定義することができます。

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :age
end

def Person(name)
    person = Person.new
    person.name = name
    person.age = 20
    person
end

p Person('yoshida').age  #=> 20
```

クラスに対して定義したい場合は、（書き方は多少変わりますが） `self.call` を定義するという手もあります。

```
class Person2
    attr_accessor :name, :age
    def self.call(name)
        person = new
        person.name = name
        person.age = 30
        person
    end
end

# 呼び出しにドットが必要
p Person2.('yoshida').age  #=> 30
```